# How to test a helper method that nullifies a member that you set with `assign`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Consider a Rails helper method `log_out`:

```
def log_out
  session.delete(:user_id)
  @current_user = nil
end
```

And an rspec helper spec test:

```
describe "#log_out" do

  before do
    helper.instance_variable_set(:@current_user, "FAKE")
    session[:user_id] = "FAKE"
  end

  it "sets the current user to nil" do
    helper.log_out
    expect(helper.instance_variable_get(:@current_user)).to be_nil
  end

end
```

This test passes. However, when I replace the `instance_variable_set` in the `before` block with `assign`, like this:

```
describe "#log_out" do

  before do
    assign(:current_user, "FAKE")
    session[:user_id] = "FAKE"
  end
  #...
```

The test fails with:

```
Failure/Error: expect(helper.instance_variable_get(:@current_user)).to be_nil
  expected: nil
       got: "FAKE"
```

The test is attempting to verify that an instance variable has been assigned `nil`. My intent is to use `assigns` instead of `instance_variable_set`. Shouldn't I be able to use `assign` and test a method that assigns that instance variable to a *new* value?

Comment: can u paste the whole code which contain the `log_out`, is it in a module?